# Excel VBA loop to check for duplication doesn't work...sometimes

Tags: excel, vba

In this loop, I check for any previous 'Random' Numbers used. However sometimes it still generates a random number that HAS previously been used? I can't understand why and would appreciate guidance on the error in my ways.

```
'Generate Random Number and check against previous
   Randomize
   randomNumberInt = Int((9999 - 1000 + 1) * Rnd + 1000)
   randomNumber = randomNumber & CStr(randomNumberInt) 'Convert the Int to a String

    For Each Month In Months 'Search all sheets in a loop
   With Sheets(Month).Range("I:I") 'Searches all of column I for the randomNumber to check if it has already been used.
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=randomNumber, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
             'MsgBox "Match Found so restart?!" 'Remove once finished

             GoTo RandomNumberGenerator_Restart 'Value found so call the Sub again to try a different number
        Else

            'Value not found so carry on...
        End If

    End With

    Next Month 'Next sheet/month

Exit Sub
```

In a previous question I had asked why were the supposed 'Random' numbers repeating in series... I had not used `Randomize` to randomize the seed number. I appreciated the chances of duplication should be very limited now, but I would still like to understand how the loop isn't stopping the repeat value from reappearing.

Edit: I should note that this error "seems" sporadic, on one occasion it runs fine, on another it throws out a previously used 'unique' random number....

Comment: A random number generates... a random number within a range. In fact, the output of a true Random number generator does not depend on the previous output. So it can generate 2, for example, several times. If you don't want previous numbers, then you have to store the output of the generator in a list, and check that the new output isn't in the list. If we know what you are planning to achieve - why you are searching the sheets - we can advise as to a better strategy

Comment: I thought I had anticipated that by checking the rand generated and then re-run the loop if it was the same as a previous random. That is what I am struggling with, why my conditions don't catch it.

Comment: The output of the generator is used, so each random generated is in the sheets. hence why I search the sheets for ones previously used and if matched, the loop should re-run until a unique random is generated. Yep there probably most definitely a better way to do this but for arguments sake, why doesn't this work?

Comment: What is Month and Months? And also the initial value of randomNumber? You do `randomNumber = randomNumber & CStr(randomNumberInt).` Why? And why change to a string?

Comment: Putting aside _why_ you are converting to string, try changing to`randomNumber = CStr(randomNumberInt)`.  Depending on where your Restart label is, after a dup is found this could give you different results from what you expect

Comment: I will try these suggestions. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

I read your code as not the whole function (the GoTo label for example is missing off the top somewhere). It might be easier to diagnose with the whole thing to copy/paste into Excel. But I did see one curious bit.

`randomNumber = randomNumber & CStr(randomNumberInt)` appears to be concatenating the new 4-digit random integer to whatever the previous value of `randomNumber` was. Is it possible you're searching for the wrong value?

Comment: Done. On the After bit is that doing something useful? Is it flushing out nasty left-over state from a previous Find? Or could one just omit it?

Comment: In this case After makes no difference,  since Find will wrap, and the OP only wants to know if the value exists at all.  Its useful when there may be several matches and  you want to find the first instance (After the last cell starts the search from the first cell)